# Buying replacement Macbook Pro Battery - Genuine vs. eBay

Tags: macbook, battery, hardware-rec

I'm looking to replace my Macbook Pro's battery (15", last model before the Unibody).  It's currently at 55% capacity (as reported in System Information and Battery Health Monitor).  I've [reset the SMC firmware](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1411), calibrated the battery, and it's just not lasting that long anymore.

I've seen some genuine replacements that are "pulls" (pulled from used computers) that are rated at least 90% capacity (iFixit, MacSales).  I've also seen a [variety of batteries on eBay](http://shop.ebay.com/?_from=R40&_trksid=p3907.m38.l1313&_nkw=MA348LL/A&_sacat=See-All-Categories) that look more like clones than genuine batteries, but are new.

A [new battery from Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MA348LL/A) is $129, and when I brought my laptop in they ran the Battery test and said if I bought the battery right then they'd give me a discount (around $100).

Anyone out there used one of these "OEM Compatible" batteries?  Fit/finish good? (I don't want a funky color or a corner that sticks out.)  Or, should I just suck it up and get the genuine replacement (for about twice the price)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally wouldn't go ebay for a laptop battery...  Not when you can go to a actual store, and get equivalent pricing.

Ebay doesn't necessarily have the lowest prices...  Check out [Google Shopping](http://www.google.com/products?q=MA348LL/A&scoring=p) ....  Lowest price is $48.53, but I would instead suggest, $64.99 from buy.com or 67.99 from Amazon...

You at least have some guarantee of reputation that way...  Batteries are not something that you play around with, unless you want to risk the battery fires from several years ago....

Comment: I always forget about Google Shopping.  The one from Buy.com is especially nice - it actually shows the bottom (what I care about :) and the connector (which I **suppose** is also important.)

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple of ebay purchased chinese batteries for my macbook pro.  I bought them the replace the dead apple factory battery because there were so many terrible reviews of the apple batteries.  The battery came from hong kong and uses the same sony manufactured lithium polymer cells that the apple batteries do.  The fit an finish is not the same as the apple batteries as the hong kong batteries are made entirely of plastic.  However I bought two of them, which both last as long or longer than my apple battery ever did, and was still 40 dollars short of what an apple battery would have cost me.  I have had both chinese batteries for about a year now and they both hold about 85% of there original capacity at around 350 cycles each.  Good luck!

Comment: Unless people can buy the same batteries, this isn't really useful information except to indicate that it's possible to buy a decent third party battery if you're lucky.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Apple Replacement ones, but I use replacements all the time for Dells.

As long as it has the voltage requirements, I wouldn't worry, I have had no problems - although, if you go the eBay route, try to find someone with a few thousand experience/track record of good products and you shouldn't have a problem

Comment: I've bought batteries (UPS, Fujitsu laptop) from eBay before and the seller rating is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to think about.

If the company actually lists a street address, it's a fairly decent indicator that they're not completely fly-by night.

Also, look at the "BBB Verified"/"Reseller Ratings"/"{Company name} Verified" logos on the page. If they're links, or hosted by the company on the label, they're likely valid. However, if they're hosted locally, and are not links, it's a sure bet they're false, which is a pretty good indicator the reseller is not trustworthy.

I've had pretty good luck with off-brand replacements (though not for apple). Generally, the capacity may be *slightly* exaggerated, but that doesn't bother me too much.